# Are anime series repeated in Japanese TV?

Tags: japan

Are seasonal anime series repeated in Japanese TV?
What about long running anime series like Naruto/One Piece? Are these repeated?

Comment: By "repeat" you mean "reruns"?  I would anecdotally suggest "yes" since that's what a lot of major broadcasters do, but it depends on what you mean there.  When do you expect that to happen - in general or at specific times? When the show is out of print/out of season (like Ranma 1/2 being shown on air again even nowadays)?  While the show is actively broadcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations from the season usually repeat the most recent episode in 1~5 different channels, deppending the popularty.
There is reruns also, but mostly very mainstream... Precure, Doraemon, etc...

Also, there is exclusive animation channels in Japan.
The ones I know are AT-X and Animax... They mainly broadcast old animations. Also AT-X is known for broadcasting uncensored animations (without stupid censorship)

Right now Animax is broadcasting Macross Delta, and AT-X Shiroi no Aquatope.